# Wordpress SUM custom fields (same post, different columns)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, inner-join

I have a problem with my SQL.
I have a custom post_type (client_sales) with several custom fields ("sale", "discount", etc)
I have more than 9000 posts and each day I have more than 100 new posts.

So I want to keep track of the total of "sale" and "discount" using just one SQL query.

```
function get_sum_from_custom_fields($posttype , $status, $fields){
    global $wpdb;

    foreach ($status as $key => $val) {
        $status[$key] = "p.post_status = '{$val}'"; 
    }
    $status = implode(" OR ", $status);

    $fields = is_array($fields) ? $fields : array($fields);

    $cols = array();
    $inners = array();

    foreach ($fields as $field) {

        $cols[] = "SUM(c_{$field}.meta_value) AS {$field}";

        $inners[] = "INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->postmeta." c_{$field}
            ON c_{$field}.post_id=p.ID
            AND c_{$field}.meta_key = '$field'";

    }
    $cols = implode(", ", $cols);
    $inners = implode(" ", $inners);

    $q ="SELECT 
    count(p.ID) AS 'count',
    $cols
    FROM 
        $wpdb->posts p
        $inners
    WHERE 1=1
        AND p.post_type = '$posttype'
        AND ($status)
        AND p.post_name NOT LIKE '%revision%' 
        AND p.post_name NOT LIKE '%autosave%'";
    echo "<pre>"; var_dump($q); echo "</pre>";
    return  $wpdb->get_results($q);

}
```

So lets say you use this function like this :

```
$posttype = 'client_sales';
$status = array(
    'discount_used',
    'in-progress',
    'discount_in_coupon'
);
$data1 = get_sum_from_custom_fields($posttype, $status,'sale');
$data2 = get_sum_from_custom_fields($posttype, $status,'discount');
$data3 = get_sum_from_custom_fields($posttype, $status, array ('sale','discount'));
```

data1 and data2 are correct while data3 returns an erroron the "sale" column.

Example :

```
$data1 would be: counts = 5000, c_sale = 2000
$data2 would be: counts = 5000, c_discount = 60
$data3 returns : counts = 5000, c_sale = 1376, c_discount = 60
```

So why do I get a difference in "c_sales" on data3? from 2000 that is correct to another number that I don't understand (1376)?

The query on data3 is:

```
SELECT 
count(p.ID) AS 'count_client_sales',
SUM(c_montant_dachats.meta_value) AS montant_dachats, SUM(c_montant_de_remise.meta_value) AS montant_de_remise
FROM 
    wp_posts p
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta c_montant_dachats
        ON c_montant_dachats.post_id=p.ID
        AND c_montant_dachats.meta_key = 'montant_dachats' INNER JOIN wp_postmeta c_montant_de_remise
        ON c_montant_de_remise.post_id=p.ID
        AND c_montant_de_remise.meta_key = 'montant_de_remise'
    WHERE 1=1
        AND p.post_type = 'client_sales'
        AND (p.post_status = 'discount_used' OR p.post_status = 'in-progress' OR p.post_status = 'discount_in_coupon')
        AND p.post_name NOT LIKE '%revision%' 
        AND p.post_name NOT LIKE '%autosave%'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to the correct solution (which is excellent, because wp_postmeta is a pain in the neck to use correctly).

But you should  use LEFT JOINs rather than INNER JOINs in the query. When you use INNER JOIN, the row from the table on the right is removed from the result set if the table on the left doesn't match. I suspect you have some rows with a `sale` postmeta and no `discount` postmeta or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much... with a LEFT JOIN everything works like a charm